# Sum amount of one day period

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I am trying to sum the total amount of user payments for one day period (24 hours..)

My query is returning all results even if dates are far from 24 hours range.

How to fix this?

```
resultDaily = $this->getPayRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('sum(p.amount) Total')
        ->where('p.date >= :end')
        ->andWhere('p.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('-1 day'))
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

I modified code. It look cleaner but gives the same result.

Edit:

```
$resultDaily = $this->getPayRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('sum(p.amount) Total')
        ->where("DATE_ADD(p.date, 24,'hour') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")
        ->andWhere('p.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    return $resultDaily;
```

Comment: Can you post the array result without groupBy ?
I don't see anything wrong in your DQL.

Comment: When I remove groupBy it trows and error: Syntax error or access violation:  In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column date; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by". @Benito103e

Comment: Yes, in fact you need to remove your select too.

Comment: So i removed one select line and groupBy and edited the code above.. I think this might be it. But event still returns all results sum not just from 1day range// @Benito103e

Comment: `->where("DATE_ADD(p.date, 24,'hour') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()")` in your edit. You're comparing 2 values against one another, which is nice, but it does not compare against any property. For example: `->andWhere("p.created_at >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-24, 'hour')")` (think that might be correctly written, did not test).

Comment: It could be, but minus (-) sign can't be put.. @rkeet

Comment: Right, replace `DATE_ADD` with `DATE_SUB` and remove '-' sign ;-)

Comment: That is what I did. Thank you so much! @rkeet

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replay.

I did it with:

```
->where("DATE(p.transactionDate) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 24, 'hour')")
```